# Just swipe effect from jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I install jQuery Mobile on my site for using swipeLeft and swipeRight effect.
But jQuery Mobile add some wrappers for my content. The wrapper has attributes like `data-role="page"` and one more with `class="ui-loader"`.

I would like using just swipe effect, without "paging".
It's possible?

Comment: yeah its possible. dont use JQM and use hammers js for swipes.  http://hammerjs.github.io/

Comment: @Tasos Thanks, I interested this, but now i build own jQuery Mobile by http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/